# Sum up columns until the cell in adjacent column is NA and then divide each of them by the preceding column[SOLVED]

Tags: r

I'm trying to add up columns in a data table until the adjacent column has a value of NA. For example, if I had the table:

| DATE | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | 2 | 12 | 12 |
| 08/01/2022 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 09/01/2022 | 3 | NA | NA |

I would only add up to row 2 in column 1, as row 3 in column 2 is NA, and row 1 in column 2. I would then divide each of those columns by the preceding column. I'd also want to ignore the date.  Is there a way to do this without hard coding it? This would be the desired end row:

| TOTAL | 3 | 12 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I tried using "adorn_table" and excluding NAs, but that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Find the `NA`, `before_first_NA = match(NA, your_data$column_with_na) - 1` then sum up those rows, `sum(your_data$column_to_add[1:before_first_NA])`, or if you have a bunch of columns `colSums(your_data[1:before_first_NA, columns_to_sum])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the original question, try:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create made-up data
df <- tibble(
  x = c(2, 1, 3),
  y = c(12, 1, NA)
)

df |>
  filter(cumsum(is.na(y)) == 0) |>  # This will get rid of all rows starting from the first time when y is NA
  summarize(                        # add up the values of x
    s = sum(x)
  ) |>
  pull(s)
```

For the clarified question, I'm assuming the number of columns is arbitrary.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a function to do the work
f <- function(.x, .y) {
  keep_rows <- cumsum(is.na(.y)) == 0
  sum(.x[keep_rows])
}

# create made-up data
df <- tibble(
  date = 1:3, # dates in your case, I'm keeping it simple
  x = c(2, 1, 3),
  y = c(12, 1, NA),
  z = c(12, NA, NA)
)

total_row <- map2(
 df |> select(x:z),  # select the columns being summed
 df |> select(y, z1 = z, z2 = z), # If you want the last column to depend on itself, you'll need to do something like this
  f
)

bind_rows(df |>
  mutate(date = as.character(date)), 
  c(date = "Total", total_row)
)
```

Comment: Not much of a difference really, but if you're going to `pull` the result it will be a little cleaner and more efficient to skip the summarize and do `filter(...) |> pull(s) |> sum()`

Comment: I agree.  I think I even thought of that after had written it out this way (and decided not to mess with it).  Mostly depends on what the OP's use case is.

Comment: Yes, it's rather unclear how OP wants to use the output.

Comment: I apologize, I want the output to be at the bottom of the table as a row. I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this without having to hard-code the variables?

Comment: What do you mean by hard-code the variables?  The `select` function is very versatile.  you can use last_col() to identify to the last column without giving it by name or (say) 2:(ncol(df) - 1).  You should be able to do a search on (say) last_col to see a list of all the ways you can use select to identify the variables without identifying them by name

Comment: The table is already created, so I'm trying to apply the function to the already existing table.

Comment: If you're column names are "1", "2", "3", etc, you can identify them by surrounding it with a `.   I can't demo it easily due to how the markdown is formatted here

Comment: The issue I'm having is argument ".y" is missing, with no default

Comment: Ahh...  see the latest change.   I don't actually have R installed on this computer, so I can't do the ideal copy/paste from R solution when answering questions.  My apologies

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it. I have one more question: how would I divide each of those column sums by the preceding one?

Comment: Just change the function in the `map2` function.  Something like `map2(list of col1s, list of col2s, ~ .x / .y)` or   `map2(list of col1s, list of col2s, ~ .y / .x)` depending on which direction you're trying to go.

Comment: That's odd. It seems to add all rows for the first column and then put NA for the others.

Comment: Think about what your column lists should be ("list of col1s" in my pseudo-code above) if you want to apply this to the totals.

Comment: I see. The only issue is getting the preceding column, as can't recycle `.x`  to match `.y`.

Comment: That is literally what I did in the `map2` solution in the answer I gave above.  You should be able to adapt that fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Define a function `sumToNA` which sums x to the position prior to the first NA in y.  If there are no NAs it sums x entirely.

Then mapply that function to DF without column 1 and DF without  the first two columns but the last column twice. No packages are used.

```
sumToNA <- function(x, y) sum(x[!cummax(is.na(y))], na.rm = TRUE)
n <- ncol(DF)
rbind(DF, c("Total", mapply(sumToNA, DF[2:n], DF[c(3:n, n)])))
##         DATE 1    2    3
## 1 07/01/2022 2   12   12
## 2 08/01/2022 1    1 <NA>
## 3 09/01/2022 3 <NA> <NA>
## 4      Total 3   12   12
```

**2)** Define a function `NAfwd` which takes a vector and returns it but with all NA's after the first NA and converts all remaining non-NA's to 0.  Then add DF[-1] to the processed DF without the first two columns and the last column twice after transforming each column with `NAfwd`.  Then use `rowSums` to sum the rows of that and insert the result as a new row.

```
NAfwd <- \(z) 0 * Reduce(\(x, y) if (is.na(x)) x else y, z, acc = TRUE)

n <- ncol(DF)
rbind(DF, c("Total", colSums(DF[-1] + apply(DF[c(3:n,n)], 2, NAfwd), na.rm=TRUE)))
##         DATE 1    2    3
## 1 07/01/2022 2   12   12
## 2 08/01/2022 1    1 <NA>
## 3 09/01/2022 3 <NA> <NA>
## 4      Total 3   12   12
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(
  DATE = c("07/01/2022", "08/01/2022", "09/01/2022"),
  `1` = c(2L, 1L, 3L),
  `2` = c(12L, 1L, NA),
  `3` = c(12L, NA, NA),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```